# Fetch uncommon records based on status

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables. I need to fetch the records from T2 which are not present in T1 based on Status.
I am not sure if I do left outer join I get all the records from T1 . I understand the reason but not sure how to fix it . Can you please guide .

T1

[image]

and T2

[image]

Output:

[image]

Query I tried.

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 
ON T2.DOC_NO=T1.DOC_NO
WHERE T2.STATUS='Cleared' and T1.STATUS !='Cleared'
```

Comment: . . " I need to fetch the records from T2 which are not present in T1 based on Status. "  This is not a clear description of what you want to do.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: If DOC_NO is cleared both in T1 and T2 I should not bring that doc no from T2..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT T2.*
  FROM T2 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM T1
    WHERE T1.DOC_NO = T2.DOC_NO
      AND T1.STATUS = 'Cleared');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on example you provided it is not clear how Status filtering is used. It looks more like you need MINUS operator:

```
select doc_no, status, amount from t2
minus
select doc_no, status, amount from t1;
```

Thanks.